# How do I get Bootstrap .span1 and .span3 to align horizontally at the top on mobile sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap framework and I'm trying to get a .span1 and a .span3 div to align horizontally on the top on mobile dimensions. When the browser window hits the breakpoint (782px) the top alignment of the image and the text to the right disappears and the text becomes horizontally centered and starts wrapping around the image.

I'm new to Stackoverflow and have a hard time determining how much code to provide. So any feedback on how I form my question would be helpful. : )

You can view the problem at http://theplaybook.co under the testimonial section.

The .span1 contains an image and the .span3 contains text. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="testimonials">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span1"><img src="/img/tyler.jpg"></div>
<div class="span3">
<p>Just did a beta test of Playbook. I am super impressed."</p>
<p>—Tyler Tervooren</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.testimonials img {
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap sets `float: none` for all the grid spans in screens smaller that `767px`. You can overwrite Bootstrap's rule for all `span*` elements or only for a specific elements by adding this code after Bootstrap's CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .testimonials .row-fluid .controls-row [class*="span"] {
        float: left !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **offsets**. The documentation here shows you how:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Spans are floated elements, so if you don't want to use offsets, then you can use span for the size but then override it's float attribute to not float, and give it "margin-right" and "margin-left" of "auto" within a div to center it.